# Поиск Яндекса в Python

Tags: python

Интересует адрес поисковой строки Яндекса, для вставки в код в Python.
У меня есть пример с гуглом

```
   def get_search(search_str):
    r = requests.get('http://www.google.com/search',
                     params={'q':f'{search_str}'}
```

При подстановке желаемого в эту функцию выполняется поиск в гугле. Интересует адрес Яндекса
Вот это:

```
http://yandex.ru/yandsearch?text=
```

Не работает, "NoneType" object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: попробуйте так: `r = requests.get('https://yandex.ru/search/', params={'text':f'{search_str}'})`

Comment: к сожалению, та же ошибка

Comment: покажите аргумент, который вы передаете в функцию: `print(search_str)`

Comment: обычный текст 'текст'

Answer (score 2):

Пример с [Яндекс.Практикума](https://praktikum.yandex.ru):

```
user_query = 'как стать бэкенд-разработчиком'         #имеется запрос
blok_list = user_query.split()                        #разбиваем слова по пробелам
url_query = '%20'.join(blok_list)                     #разделяем их через %20
url = 'https://yandex.ru/search/?text=' + url_query + '&lr=213'   #подставляем
print(url)
```

Не забудьте в конце добавить `'&lr=213'` — имя технического параметра.

Answer (score 1):

```
def get_search(search_str):
 r = requests.get('https://yandex.ru/yandsearch',
                  params={'q':f'{search_str}'}
```